# No line is printed out, in command box, when running a .Net Console app through Ruby system call

Tags: .net, ruby, console-application, sketchup

There is a simple C# console application which only prints out 'Hello'.
And also a Ruby plugin which works in Sketchup 2014 is supposed to run the above app.
(Ruby code used to run the app: `"C:/s/Test.exe"`)

It runs and works fine but nothing is displayed in the command box, whereas it shows 'Hello' in Sketchup 2013 or from outside Sketchup.

The only difference between Sketchup 2014 and 2013 is the former uses Ruby 2.0 and the later 1.8.

Does anyone know what possibly could be the reason?
I appropriate any help or workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something broke when the Ruby interpreter was upgraded to 2.0 in SketchUp. We don't know what caused it. The current workaround is to pipe the output to a temp file and read the file.

```
`C:/s/Test.exe > sometempfile.txt`
```

Comment: It didn't happen though when tried it on a machine with windows 8.

Comment: When run in windows 8, the command box displayed the outputs.